# ¿Cómo se puede convertir un pdf con OCR a PDF/A sin modificar el OCR?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

Estoy convirtiendo archivos pdf a PDF/A, los archivos originales son pdf que contienen imágenes con OCR, el problema está en que el archivo final, el PDF/A, termina con el OCR degradado, o sea, las palabras han sido cambiadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que uso para realizar la conversión es ([GhostPDL.NET](https://github.com/claudineyqr/GhostPDL.NET)):

```
var pdfContentByte = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(_file?.FullName ?? string.Empty);
var ghostProcessor = new GhostPdlProcessorPdfA();
byte[] bytes = await ghostProcessor.ConvertAsync(pdfContentByte, PdfAProfile.A1B);
byte[] rawPdfA = bytes;
if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(newPathFull, rawPdfA);
```

La switches que uso son:

```
var switches = new List<string>
            {
                "-sColorConversionStrategy=RGB",
                "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
                $"-sOutputFile={fileTempOutput}",
                $"-dPDFA={(int)pdfAProfile}",
                "-dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1",
                "-dPDFSETTINGS=/default",
                "-dAutoRotatePages=/All",
                "-dEmbedAllFonts=true",
                "-sUseOCR=Never",
                $"{_filePdfADef}",
                "-f",                
                fileTempInput
            };
```

¿Hay alguna manera de convertirlos sin dañar el OCR que se obtiene del archivo original?
No importa si no es con GhostPDL.

Comment: Las herramientas de OCR gratuitas suelen ser demasiado imprecisas. Si deseas conversión avanzada y con un margen de error muchísimo menor, puedes optar por usar algoritmos en la nube como Google Cloud Vision o entrenar tu propio algoritmo de IA, pero esta opción demora mucho tiempo. También ten en cuenta que es importante procesar la imagen antes de pasársela al algoritmo, eso puede incluir cambiar el brillo, contraste, etc; con el fin de que se vea más nítida y el algoritmo no tenga muchos problemas reconociendo las letras.

Comment: Gracias @RodrigoRamírez por tu respuesta, sucede que mi problema no radica en que esté procesando mal el OCR, sino que estoy haciendo una conversión desde pdf a PDF/A, pero el OCR del documento original se está dañando, quiero que el OCR del pdf original pase al PDF/A sin que se dañe o modifique o por lo menos que no le cambie el orden a las letras/palabras.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente libreria

iText7 : iText es una popular biblioteca de manipulación de PDF en Java y .NET que admite la conversión a PDF/A. Ofrece muchas funciones de manipulación de PDF y puede ser una buena opción si deseas un mayor control sobre el proceso de conversión.

Te dejo el link de la documentacion [aqui](https://itextpdf.com/itext-suite-net-c)